# What setting does my nikon 5300 have to be on to use my spotter scope?

Tags: nikon, adapter

I would like to use my DSLR 5300 with my spotter scope. I have a t-ring and have attached it all up no problem but when I turn the camera on it says no lens attatched. Can anyone advise me on the setting I need so they can work together or what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is a "non-CPU lens". The camera must be in camera Manual mode M. Exposure settings are manual. The scope is of course manual focus.

See D5300 REFERENCE manual, page 228.
The REFERENCE manual is available at http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/25/D5300.html